# How to configure bean validation programatically?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

Codes where i want to use bean validation:

```
@Inject
private ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;
....

public Response create(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
        Set<ConstraintViolation<UserDTO>> validate = validatorFactory.getValidator().validate(userDTO);
        validate.forEach(error-> System.err.println(error.getMessage()));
        if(validate.size() > 0){
            throw new ValidationException("userDTO is not valid!");
        }
        ...
}


public Response update(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<UserDTO>> validate = validatorFactory.getValidator().validate(userDTO);
        validate.forEach(error-> System.err.println(error.getMessage()));
        if(validate.size() > 0){
            throw new ValidationException("userDTO is not valid!");
        }
        ...
}
```

UserDTO:

```
public class UserDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String userName;
    @NotNull(message = "is missing")
    private String locked;
    @Email(message = "email is not valid")
    private String email;
    @NotNull(message = "countryCode is missing")
    private String countryCode;
    ...getters-setters more variables...
}
```

So i have a post Http method where i want to create a user...bean validation is working if missing countrycode or locked  ok or if email not valid ok...But when i want to just update for example email the validation is also run on the whole dto class...so the question is can i and how can i configure  not to run on every variable each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Validator::validateProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html#validateProperty-T-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) to check specifc properties. You can also group them and check it via [`Validator::validate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html#validate-T-java.lang.Class...-) (see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) for tutorial) if there are more than one property.